# url parsing javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<a href="?action=add&question=149&cat=88">Answer</a>'
```

this is the url i needed to get href value i cannot use element.getAttribute. I cannot use dom parsing.
 But if i try to parse it using search mechanism

```
td3_element = <td valign="top">
<a href="?action=add&question=149&cat=88">Answer</a>
</td>

href_start = td3_element.search("<a href=") + 8;
td3_part   = td3_element.substring(href_start);
href_end   = td3_part.search(">Answer</a>");
href_element = td3_part.substring(0,href_end);

href_element will only be till `?action=addamp`
```

it is taking the

```
;
```

character coming after `amp` as  end of line and it is terminating search to that point. Can some one tell me a solution which will give the desired href without using DOM parser

Comment: Why you can't use element.getAttribute()

Comment: i'm using it as a part of firefox extension development there i'have to parse certain part of my code without using element.getAttribute() .bcoz i will get the element from ajax call i tried XML Parsing appending the element to a Div and parsing it nothing worked so i'm going this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a regular expression? I'm not sure what you mean just by 'search mechanism'.

For example:

```
var htmlString = 'td3...(etc)';
var regex = /href="([^"])"/;
var hrefUrl = regex.exec()[1];
console.log(hrefUrl); //?action=add&question=149&cat=88
```

See also [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qfd8Z/)

Answer (score 0):

Try a regex

```
var a='<a href="?action=add&question=149&cat=88">Answer</a>';
a.match(/href="(.*)"/)[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

**[JSBIN Demo](http://jsbin.com/ulejek/1/)**

Creating a temp div, setting the innerHtml and parsing,

```
var str = '<a href="?action=add&question=149&cat=88">Answer</a>';

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;

document.write(div.childNodes[0].getAttribute('href'))
```